# google spreadsheets FILTER multiple ranges/columns (A13:B and E13:G)

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if it's possible to use multiple ranges/columns when using FILTER

Right now I'm simply using the formula multiple times, like so:

```
=filter((Sheet1!A13:B),Sheet1!N13:N>E2,not(iferror(search("AS -", Sheet1!O13:O))))

=filter((Sheet1!E13:G),Sheet1!N13:N>E2,not(iferror(search("AS -", Sheet1!O13:O))))
```

I'm wondering if something like this would be possible (example below doesn't work)?

```
=filter((Sheet1!A13:B,Sheet1!E13:G),Sheet1!N13:N>E2,not(iferror(search("AS -", Sheet1!O13:O))))
```

I know using QUERY is easier in this case, but I'd like to know if I can do the same with FILTER (since I haven't been able to figure it out)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using [array notation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) (curly braces), for example

```
=filter({Sheet1!A13:B,Sheet1!E13:G}, Sheet1!N13:N>E2)
```

The notation `{range1, range2, range3}` means putting these ranges side by side (they must have the same number of rows). Similarly, `{range1; range2; range3}` means stacking them vertically (they must have the same number of columns).

Comment: Note: For countries that use commas as decimal separators (for example €1,00), commas would be replaced by backslashes (\\) when creating arrays.

Comment: very important comment

Comment: if i stack vertically, what do i put as the filter condition?

Comment: I am able to successfully copy data from one sheet to another using filter in few of columns of my new target sheet, however I am also updating by appending few more columns but issue is those append data remains as it is but filter data might changes over times, those are not remaining in sync , I can surely share sample file in case you need it , but any thoughtful idea to make my copied filter data in sync with new updated data (in same row)