# Google Sheets FILTER array notation with exclusion

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently using filter formula on Google sheets and am trying to find a way to exclude cells that meet a specific criteria from this.

Here is a link to what I am using, and I'm trying to get it to say, if column X is populated, exclude it from the filter.

[FILTER multiple ranges/columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082064/21127817)

I'm currently using this and it works really well, but I've been asked to exclude items, but don't know how to do this.

Example from the link in my question:

=filter({Sheet1!A13:B,Sheet1!E13:G}, Sheet1!N13:N>E2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNTIF, try:

```
=filter({Sheet1!A13:B,Sheet1!E13:G}, Sheet1!N13:N>E2, not(countif(items_to_exclude, column_where_items_to_exclude_are_located)))
```